# Using grails filterpane plugin with one "search" input field

Tags: grails

is it possible to use the grails [filterpane-plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/filterpane) in a way that uses just one search box? i know it seems a little odd, because obviously the whole thing about this plugin that the user can specify what attributes should be filtered in what kind and with whatever filter terms.

What i would like to achieve is, that the user can search for any attribute that is displayed in the grid like it is possible in this [jira](http://jira.grails.org/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20GRAILS%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%20%222.4%22%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20priority%20%3D%20Major%20ORDER%20BY%20key%20DESC) example. i know i could come up with something like the [searchable plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/searchable) to get that done, but im not sure how i could combine this with the standard filter activities that are provided by the filterpane plugin, so i'm looking for a solution that is based on filterpane. If you have any advice or opinion about the searchable-plugin solution, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [quick search plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/quick-search) for this in my app.

Comment: thx, is it possible to combine this with the filterpane plugin, so that if a given filter is set via the filterpane plugin the search result is combined on the gorm level (especially in the WHERE clause of the sql query)?

Comment: Not out of the box, but I actually think this would be a reasonably straightforward change to the filterpane plugin. Quick search allows you to pass in a criteria closure to be 'anded' with the rest of the query, so you could modify the filterpane plugin to just return the criteria closure it builds (rather than executing it) and pass that to quick search.